# eclipes subversive connector network error

Tags: eclipse, subversive

Eclipse says it can't find the svn connector due to a network problem.
However, it was confirmed that the network is working well and that it enters the Eclipse Marketplace well.
How should I handle errors like this?

Error message

[image: 1]

I tried to attach the connector by manual install but it didn't work

Comment: What versions are you running?

Comment: Please tell the Subversive version (as nitind already said). For latest Subversive version, _Help > Install New Software..._ and working with the update site [`https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site`](https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site) works for me (using the _SVNKit 1.8.14_ connector).

Comment: Subversive version is 4.0.5

Comment: When I used that link, it was installed and solved. thank you howlger!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As workaround, go to ***Help > Install New Software...*** and work with the update site <s>[**`https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site`**](https://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site)</s> to install the SVNKit 1.8.14 or another connector.

**Update**: See [Nicolas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76778958/6505250) and use the the following update site instead:
[**`https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/`**](https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/)

The subdomain `community.polarion.com` is gone. As Polarion has been bought by Siemens some time ago, it seems that the domain `polarion.com` get abandoned: [`https://www.polarion.com`](https://www.polarion.com) redirects now to [`https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/`](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/).

Comment: polarion site is down, you can use https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/ instead

Comment: I'm actually unable to connect to https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/ as well. The error I get is org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException. It's really a connection timeout when I expand the details in the modal, though.

Comment: @JohnWhite For me `https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/` works. Maybe something temporary or something on your side. Better comment on Nicolas' answer.

Answer (score 3):

The polarion site is offline, eclipse has a new URL to use (from [Eclipse dev site](https://eclipse.dev/subversive/installation-instructions.php) )

https://osspit.org/eclipse/subversive-connectors/